# Why do I have an incompatible pointer types waning but code still works?

Tags: c, pointers

I got this warning: `incompatible pointer types passing 'char (*)[1024]' to parameter of type 'char *'`

My code looks like this:

```
myfunc(char* sString, size_t s_tString)
{
   memset(sString, '\0', s_tString);
   ...
   fPipe = (FILE *)popen (sString, "r");
   ...
}

int main()
{ 
   ...
   char sString[1024];
   myfunc(&sString, sizeof(sString));
   ...
}
```

After calling myfunc sString has the value I was expecting but the compiler throws that warning... After asking some coworkers I get why I'm getting that warning but we don't know why the code is still working.

I'm looking for the explanation of why this happens, the fix is pretty simple, rmove the & from the call.

Comment: It still works because the address of an array is the same the address of its first member. That's by design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `sString` is will decay to a pointer to its first element, i.e. `&sString[0]` which is of type `char *`.

When you use `&sString` you get a pointer to the *array*, which is of type `char (*)[1024]`.

Those two pointers are semantically *very* different, but fortunately for you they both point to the same location so the function you call works as expected.

To solve the warning, drop the address-of operator `&` in the call, so only do

```
myfunc(sString, sizeof(string));
//     ^
// Note: No & here
```

Answer (score 2):

It works since the actual value of `&sString` and `sString` end up being the same. The types differ, which triggers the warning, but the address the called function sees is still sane, i.e. it can be treated as a character buffer.

This is because there is no run-time memory representing `sString` itself, so all the compiler can do when you take its address is return the address of the first element.